# Logging array indices, not values (JavaScript) - why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my script:

```
var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "3", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var str = [];

for (i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
    str.push(i);
    console.log(str.join(""));
}
```

It's printing out the indices of str (0, 01, 012...) rather than the values (A, AB, ABC...). What is going on here?

Comment: `alphabet[i]` will give you what you need. You may want to [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in loop (`push(i)` instead of `push(alphabet[i])`). Correct loop:

```
for (i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
    str.push(alphabet[i]);
    console.log(str.join(""));
}
```